# How to optimize the mysql query with more the 20 millions records

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am using MySQL for my project, and have more than 20 million records in "mixpanel_data" table.

So when I am trying to fetch last 6 months' records then it breaks the request. It provides me with only the last 5-10 days' records only

I am using the following MySQL query.

```
SELECT  `sb_users`.`id`,`sb_users`.`name`, SUM(`mixpanel_data`.duration) as timeCount,
        COUNT(`mixpanel_data`.spread_id) as PageCount,`mixpanel_data`.`language`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`created_at`, `mixpanel_data`.`book_name`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`email`, `mixpanel_data`.`ip_address`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`event_date`, `mixpanel_data`.`type`,
        'Read', `mixpanel_data`.`unique_session_id`, `mixpanel_data`.`operating_system`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`country`, `mixpanel_data`.`region`, `mixpanel_data`.`city`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`device`, `mixpanel_data`.`browser`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`browser_version`
    FROM  `mixpanel_data`
    LEFT JOIN  `sb_users`  ON `mixpanel_data`.`first_name` = `sb_users`.`username`
    WHERE  `mixpanel_data`.`email` !=''
      AND  `mixpanel_data`.`created_at` Between '2019-03-24' AND '2020-03-24'
      and  `mixpanel_data`.`action` IN('PauseAudio')
    GROUP BY  `mixpanel_data`.`email`, `mixpanel_data`.`book_name` ,
        `mixpanel_data`.`language`
 UNION 
 SELECT  `sb_users`.`id`,`sb_users`.`name`, SUM(`mixpanel_data`.duration) as timeCount,
        COUNT(`mixpanel_data`.spread_id) as PageCount,`mixpanel_data`.`language`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`created_at`, `mixpanel_data`.`book_name`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`email`, `mixpanel_data`.`ip_address`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`event_date`, `mixpanel_data`.`type`,
        'Read', `mixpanel_data`.`unique_session_id`, `mixpanel_data`.`operating_system`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`country`, `mixpanel_data`.`region`, `mixpanel_data`.`city`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`device`, `mixpanel_data`.`browser`,
        `mixpanel_data`.`browser_version`
    FROM  `mixpanel_data`
    LEFT JOIN  `sb_users`  ON `mixpanel_data`.`first_name` = `sb_users`.`username`
    WHERE  `mixpanel_data`.`email` !=''
      AND  `mixpanel_data`.`created_at` Between '2019-03-24' AND '2020-03-24'
      and  `mixpanel_data`.`action` NOT IN('PlayAudio','PauseAudio')
      AND  `mixpanel_data`.`spread_id` !=''
    GROUP BY  `mixpanel_data`.`email`, `mixpanel_data`.`book_name` ,
        `mixpanel_data`.`language`
```

I tried to change my query with the following query, but it's not working for me. It also breaks the request and is also giving me fewer records.

```
SELECT sb_users.id,
sb_users.NAME,
Count(mixpanel_data.spread_id) AS PageCount,
SUM(CASE When action IN ('PauseAudio') Then duration Else 0 End) as total, SUM(CASE When action NOT IN ('PlayAudio', 'PauseAudio') Then duration Else 0 End) as Sectotal,
mixpanel_data.language,
mixpanel_data.created_at,
mixpanel_data.book_name,
mixpanel_data.email,
mixpanel_data.ip_address,
mixpanel_data.event_date,
mixpanel_data.type,
'Read',
mixpanel_data.unique_session_id,
mixpanel_data.operating_system,
mixpanel_data.country,
mixpanel_data.region,
mixpanel_data.city,
mixpanel_data.device,
mixpanel_data.browser,
mixpanel_data.browser_version
FROM `mixpanel_data`
LEFT JOIN sb_users
ON `mixpanel_data`.`first_name` = `sb_users`. `username`
WHERE
mixpanel_data.email != '' AND mixpanel_data.`created_at` Between '2019-03-24' AND '2020-03-24'
AND `mixpanel_data`.`spread_id` !='' GROUP BY mixpanel_data.email,
mixpanel_data.book_name,
mixpanel_data.language
```

I have also tried to add indexer on first_name, username and created_at column. But query takes lots of time (More than 15-16 seconds)

Can Anybody help me to optimize the query?

Comment: What do you mean by *"it breaks the request."*? and then only sends a portion of the results? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Your query is invalid. You group by `email, book_name, language`, but select `browser_version` for instance. Which browser version for a group? The greatest? The smallest? Same for `event_date`, `type`, `region`, etc. As you seem to be struggling with the concept of aggregation groups, I suggest you `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` to help you build a valid query. (Without that setting, MySQL circumvents your query's flaws by returning arbitrary values, which often means undesired results.)

Comment: If you expect the browser version, type, etc. to be the same per group, then you even have an issue with your data model and should normalize it, before writing any queries.

Answer (score 0):

This index on `sb_users` may help:  `INDEX(username, name, id)`.

Switching from `UNION` to `UNION ALL` should speed up the query.  But it may lead to duplicate rows.

You are fetching a year's worth of data; what percentage of the table is that?  If that is a large percentage, then no index on `mixpanel_data` would be useful.

The `GROUP BY` may be inappropriate unless you have `UNIQUE(book_name, email, language)`.  For, what if the user looks at the same book from two different ip_addresses; which ip_address would be delivered by the query?

Assuming the only differences between the `SELECTs` are

```
      and  ma.`action` IN('PauseAudio')
```

versus

```
      and  ma.`action` NOT IN('PlayAudio','PauseAudio')
      AND  ma.`spread_id` !=''
```

consider the following -- *if* you are using MySQL 8.0:

```
WITH cte AS
        SELECT ...
            FROM  `mixpanel_data` AS ma
            LEFT JOIN  `sb_users` AS su
               ON ma.`first_name` = su.`username`
            WHERE  ma.`email` !=''
              AND  ma.`created_at` >= '2019-03-24'
              AND  ma.`created_at`  < '2019-03-24' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
SELECT * FROM cte
      WHERE `action` IN('PauseAudio')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte
      WHERE `action` NOT IN('PlayAudio','PauseAudio')
        AND `spread_id` !=''
GROUP BY  `email`, `book_name` , `language`
```

The hope is that that leads to scanning `mixpanel_data` only once.

Another approach (and does not depend on 8.0):  Have an inner query ("derived table") that cods tall the work with `mixpanel_data`, *then* `JOIN` to `sb_users`:

```
 SELECT ...
     FROM ( SELECT ...
               FROM mixpanel_data
               -- (no JOIN)
               WHERE ...
               GROUP BY ...
            UNION ALL
               FROM mixpanel_data
               -- (no JOIN)
               WHERE ... (the other)
               GROUP BY ...
          )
    LEFT JOIN sb_users ON ...
```

The advantage of this is that it is not hauling around sb_user data throughout all the work.  Instead it fetching from sb_user *after* shrinking the number of rows via the `GROUP BY`.

There may be more tips; please do some of the above, then provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` and some table sizes.

That was the first query.  The **second query** differs in a couple of ways:

- the test of `spread_id` is missing
- the de-dupping of the `UNION` may lead to a different set of rows.

My suggestion about `JOINing` to `sb_users` *after* doing the `GROUP BY` applies here, too (though without the `UNION`).

**Debugging**

1. `SELECT ... FROM mixpanel_data` without the `SUM`, `COUNT`, and `GROUP BY`, but add a `LIMIT`.  See if the data looks like you expect.
2. Add in the `SUM`, `COUNT`, and `GROUP BY`; eyeball those results.
3. Then `JOIN` to the other table.